Stream Audio to Azure Real Time Diarization Service
I have an udp stream of audio that I want to transcribe as close as possible to real time.
For it, I'm using Azure Speech service (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/get-started-stt-diarization?tabs=windows&pivots=programming-language-python) in python.
Using the microphone as source input, the system works pretty well. Nevertheless, when trying to use the PullAudioStreamCallback option, the service doesn't even go inside the read method.
Any thoughts on this approach?
class MyAudioStream(speechsdk.audio.PullAudioInputStreamCallback):
    def __init__(self, socket, channel):
        super().__init__()
        print("Init")
        self.socket = socket
        self.channel = channel  # Channel 0 for left, 1 for right
        self.buffer = bytearray()

    def read(self, buffer_size):
        # Fetch new data from socket if buffer is insufficient
        while len(self.buffer) < buffer_size * 2:  # x2 because stereo data
            data, _ = self.socket.recvfrom(buffer_size * 2)
            self.buffer.extend(data)

        # Extract the requested buffer size * 2 (to handle stereo data)
        data = self.buffer[:buffer_size * 2]
        del self.buffer[:buffer_size * 2]

        # Assuming 16-bit samples, split the stereo into mono
        audio_data = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16)  # Read data as 16-bit samples
        mono_data = audio_data[self.channel::2]  # Extract one channel
        # print(audio_data)
        return mono_data.tobytes()

    def close(self):
        print("Closed")
        self.socket.close()
        
def conversation_transcriber_recognition_canceled_cb(evt: speechsdk.SessionEventArgs):
    print('Canceled event')

def conversation_transcriber_session_stopped_cb(evt: speechsdk.SessionEventArgs):
    print('SessionStopped event')

def conversation_transcriber_transcribed_cb(evt: speechsdk.SpeechRecognitionEventArgs, file_handle):
    if evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
        s_id, text = evt.result.speaker_id, evt.result.text
        file_handle.write('Speaker ID={}: {}\n'.format(s_id, text))
        print('Speaker ID={}: {}\n'.format(s_id, text))
    elif evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
        file_handle.write('NOMATCH: Speech could not be TRANSCRIBED: {}\n'.format(evt.result.no_match_details))


def conversation_transcriber_session_started_cb(evt: speechsdk.SessionEventArgs):
    print('SessionStarted event')


def create_transcriber(sock, sample_rate, channel):
    
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=key_, region=region_)
    speech_config.speech_recognition_language="en-US"
    # Set the expected audio format (monaural)
    audio_format = speechsdk.audio.AudioStreamFormat(samples_per_second=sample_rate, bits_per_sample=16, channels=1)
    # Create an instance of PullAudioInputStream with the custom stream callback
    stream_callback = MyAudioStream(sock, channel)
    audio_input = speechsdk.audio.PullAudioInputStream(stream_callback, audio_format)
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(stream=audio_input)
    conversation_transcriber = speechsdk.transcription.ConversationTranscriber(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

    return conversation_transcriber 

def main():
    # Setup the UDP socket common for both channels
    UDP_IP = MY_IP
    UDP_PORT = MY_PORT
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
      
    transcribing_stop = False
    conversation_transcriber = create_transcriber(sock, 16000, 0)

    def stop_cb(evt: speechsdk.SessionEventArgs):
        #"""callback that signals to stop continuous recognition upon receiving an event `evt`"""
        print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
        nonlocal transcribing_stop
        transcribing_stop = True

    output_file_path = "test.txt"
    with open(output_file_path, 'w') as file_handle:
        conversation_transcriber.transcribed.connect(lambda evt: conversation_transcriber_transcribed_cb(evt, file_handle))
        conversation_transcriber.session_started.connect(conversation_transcriber_session_started_cb)
        conversation_transcriber.session_stopped.connect(conversation_transcriber_session_stopped_cb)
        conversation_transcriber.canceled.connect(conversation_transcriber_recognition_canceled_cb)
        conversation_transcriber.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
        conversation_transcriber.canceled.connect(stop_cb)

        conversation_transcriber.start_transcribing_async()

        try:
            while not transcribing_stop:
                time.sleep(.5)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            conversation_transcriber.stop_transcribing_async()
            conversation_transcriber.close()
            sock.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
      main()

Alternatively, I have tested the system streaming the data through HTTP and using a PushAudioInputStream object instead. In this case, the data seem to arrive to azure but the recognition part always comes back empty.
This is the code for the second test:
def transcribe_stream(stream_url):
            
    # Initialize the Azure Speech SDK
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=key_, region=region_)
    # Using a pull stream to get audio from an HTTP stream
    stream = speechsdk.audio.PushAudioInputStream()
    audio_input = speechsdk.AudioConfig(stream=stream)
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_input)

    # Function to handle recognized text
    def recognized(args):
        if args.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
            print(args)
            print("Recognized: {}".format(args.result.text))
        elif args.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
            print("No speech could be recognized")

    # Connect to the recognizer's events
    speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(recognized)

    # Begin continuous speech recognition
    speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
    try:
        # Stream the audio from the HTTP source
        with requests.get(stream_url, stream=True) as r:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                if chunk:
                    stream.write(chunk)
            stream.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error streaming audio: {e}")
    finally:
        # Stop the continuous recognition once the stream ends
        print("END")
        speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()

# URL of the VLC stream
stream_url = 'http://my_address/end_point'
transcribe_stream(stream_url)

Any guidance is appreciated :)

To integrate the provided code snippets with Azure Speech service for real-time diarization of an audio stream received via UDP, we need a UDP connection to be established between the server and the client.

Unlike TCP, UDP does not provide reliability or ordering guarantees. Therefore, the server simply sends audio data packets to the client without waiting for acknowledgment.
The client receives the packets and plays back the audio. So, we play the received audio using Azure Speech service for diarization.

I referred to this link for streaming audio data over UDP sockets.
import socket
import threading
import wave
import pyaudio
import time
import math

host_ip = '192.168.1.104'  # Change this to the server's IP address
port = 9633

def audio_stream_UDP():
    BUFF_SIZE = 65536
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, BUFF_SIZE)
    server_socket.bind((host_ip, port))

    CHUNK = 10 * 1024
    wf = wave.open("temp.wav", 'rb')
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    print('Server listening at', (host_ip, port), wf.getframerate())
    stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                    channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                    rate=wf.getframerate(),
                    input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    sample_rate = wf.getframerate()
    while True:
        msg, client_addr = server_socket.recvfrom(BUFF_SIZE)
        print('Got connection from', client_addr, msg)
        
        DATA_SIZE = math.ceil(wf.getnframes() / CHUNK)
        DATA_SIZE = str(DATA_SIZE).encode()
        print('Sending data size...', wf.getnframes() / sample_rate)
        server_socket.sendto(DATA_SIZE, client_addr)
        cnt = 0
        while True:
            data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
            server_socket.sendto(data, client_addr)
            time.sleep(0.001)  # Adjust the delay according to your requirements
            print(cnt)
            if cnt > (wf.getnframes() / CHUNK):
                break
            cnt += 1

        break
    print('Data transmission complete')

t1 = threading.Thread(target=audio_stream_UDP, args=())
t1.start()


I referred to this link for Azure Speech service.
class MyAudioStream(speechsdk.audio.PullAudioInputStreamCallback):
    def __init__(self, socket, channel):
        super().__init__()
        print("Init")
        self.socket = socket
        self.channel = channel  # Channel 0 for left, 1 for right
        self.buffer = bytearray()

    def read(self, buffer_size):
        # Fetch new data from socket if buffer is insufficient
        while len(self.buffer) < buffer_size * 2:  # x2 because stereo data
            data, _ = self.socket.recvfrom(buffer_size * 2)
            self.buffer.extend(data)

      
        data = self.buffer[:buffer_size * 2]
        del self.buffer[:buffer_size * 2]

        # Assuming 16-bit samples, split the stereo into mono
        audio_data = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16)  # Read data as 16-bit samples
        mono_data = audio_data[self.channel::2]  # Extract one channel
        return mono_data.tobytes()

    def close(self):
        print("Closed")
        self.socket.close()

def conversation_transcriber_transcribed_cb(evt: speechsdk.SpeechRecognitionEventArgs, file_handle):
    if evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
        s_id, text = evt.result.speaker_id, evt.result.text
        file_handle.write('Speaker ID={}: {}\n'.format(s_id, text))
        print('Speaker ID={}: {}\n'.format(s_id, text))
    elif evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
        file_handle.write('NOMATCH: Speech could not be TRANSCRIBED: {}\n'.format(evt.result.no_match_details))

def create_transcriber(sock, sample_rate, channel):
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=key_, region=region_)
    speech_config.speech_recognition_language="en-US"
    # Set the expected audio format (monaural)
    audio_format = speechsdk.audio.AudioStreamFormat(samples_per_second=sample_rate, bits_per_sample=16, channels=1)
    
    stream_callback = MyAudioStream(sock, channel)
    audio_input = speechsdk.audio.PullAudioInputStream(stream_callback, audio_format)
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(stream=audio_input)
    conversation_transcriber = speechsdk.transcription.ConversationTranscriber(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

    return conversation_transcriber 

def main():
    # Setup the UDP socket common for both channels
    UDP_IP = "YourIPAddress"
    UDP_PORT = 12345  # Replace with your UDP port
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
      
    transcribing_stop = False
    conversation_transcriber = create_transcriber(sock, 16000, 0)

    def stop_cb(evt: speechsdk.SessionEventArgs):
        print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
        nonlocal transcribing_stop
        transcribing_stop = True

    output_file_path = "transcription.txt"
    with open(output_file_path, 'w') as file_handle:
        conversation_transcriber.transcribed.connect(lambda evt: conversation_transcriber_transcribed_cb(evt, file_handle))
        conversation_transcriber.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)

        conversation_transcriber.start_transcribing_async()

        try:
            while not transcribing_stop:
                time.sleep(.5)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            conversation_transcriber.stop_transcribing_async()
            conversation_transcriber.close()
            sock.close()



For alternative methods of using a UDP channel as input for the ConversationTranscriber, please refer to this link .

Thanks for your answer!
I'm not super sure how to use it tho...
Are you running both scripts in parallel? And then, the first script is streaming the temp.wav file?
In this case, I have a UDP feed that I don't control and I want to keep the connection open and transcribe the signal when there is a conversation ongoing. How would this change the set up?
Thanks for your help :)

no need to run in parallel .Yes, the first script provided is responsible for streaming the temp.wav file over UDP.To continuously transcribe an audio stream received via UDP using the Azure Speech service for real-time diarization, set up a client that binds to a UDP port to receive the audio data stream. The client should use a custom audio stream class to handle the incoming audio data and feed it to the Azure Speech service.

thanks. To test the scripts I try to run both in parallel to simulate my udp feed. In that case, I first run the server script but then, when I try to connect to the port where the stream is happening, windows refuses since the port is occupied.
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
Sorry if the question is too dumb but I'm not sure how to bypass this.
I'm running both scripts on the same machine

When running both the server and client scripts on the same machine, it's essential to ensure they don't attempt to use the same port simultaneously. This is because a port can only be occupied by one process at a time. To address this, you can modify one of the scripts to use a different port.
